# detect if link between stored reference and DOM element is broken

Tags: javascript

I have recently discovered a following problem:

- store reference to DOM element (i.e. span) so you can operate on it faster without continuously DOM raiding to find it
- run operation that does something to/with DOM element that reference to you have stored
- add dynamically new DOM element using `.innerHTML += '<span id="some_id">0</span>'`
- observe how view is not updated anymore based on the reference you stored

Meaning that link between your stored reference and DOM element is broken.
Operation that i need to do on the element is running on short interval (60 times per second) so i am forced now to execute `document.getElementById()` 60 times per second which affects performance on old devices significantly.

I tried to debug this problem and i found that element is still connected inside reference and operation is still running, it just stopped updating view, so i have no clue how to fix this.

Ideally it could be good to have a check if link is broken and re-link it. Does anyone have a clue how it can be done?

Test code:

```js
var pool = [];

var check_pool_state = function(index) {
 console.log( pool[index] );
};

var increase = function(id) {
 
 var dom_element = document.getElementById(id);
 
 var next = pool.length;
 
 pool[next] = {
  element: dom_element,
  value: parseInt(dom_element.innerText),
  update: function() {
   var self = this;
   setInterval(function() {
    self.value++;
    self.element.innerText = self.value;
   }, 50);
  }
 };
 
 pool[next].update();
 
};

increase('test');

// add new element to DOM after 2 seconds using += innerHTML 
setTimeout(function() {
 document.body.innerHTML += '<span id="another_test">0</span>';
 setInterval(function() {
  check_pool_state('0');
 }, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

```css
span {
 display:block;
 background:#efefef;
 padding:20px;
 float:left;
 width:200px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:arial;
 margin-right:20px;
 font-size:40px;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.69);
 border:solid 2px #ccc;
 border-radius:4px;
 color:#929292;
}
```

```html
<span id="test">0</span>
```

Fiddle [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/hL23efme/) to play with the code.

In console logs you can see that after new element is added reference is still in object but it doesnt correspond anymore to displayed in view element.

**---------------  EDIT  ---------------**

I forgot to mention that unfortunately scripts that add elements dynamically are third parties scripts and i dont control them so i cannot switch adding method to `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML`. That said i will have to either detect if link is broken or if document has been re-parsed or something like that.

I also found out that this check:

```
( document.getElementById(__DOM__ID__) === self.element )
```

returns false after link is broken, but i am not sure if it helps much as i am still executing `getElementById` in every tick of operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) so as not to corrupt the reference to the old node. When you use (`+=` or `=`) `.innerHTML`, the contents of the container are parsed back into a string, the container is cleared, the string you're adding gets appended to the existing string, and then the concatenated string gets re-parsed as HTML - so, it makes sense that old references are lost.

For example:

```js
var pool = [];

var check_pool_state = function(index) {
  console.log(pool[index]);
};

var increase = function(id) {

  var dom_element = document.getElementById(id);

  var next = pool.length;

  pool[next] = {
    element: dom_element,
    value: parseInt(dom_element.innerText),
    update: function() {
      var self = this;
      setInterval(function() {
        self.value++;
        self.element.innerText = self.value;
      }, 50);
    }
  };

  pool[next].update();

};

increase('test');

// add new element to DOM after 2 seconds using += innerHTML 
setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span id="another_test">0</span>');
  setTimeout(function() {
    increase('another_test');
  }, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.69);
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #929292;
}
```

```html
<span id="test">0</span>
```

If you don't have control over how the element is inserted, then another option would be to use [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to see if the node is still part of the DOM. Stack snippets aren't working quite right with your full example, so to show a simplified version:

```js
const test = document.querySelector('#test');
console.log(document.body.contains(test));
document.body.innerHTML += '<span id="test2">0</span>';
console.log(document.body.contains(test));
```

```html
<span id="test">0</span>
```

Another option, check to see if the element's parent exists:

```js
const test = document.querySelector('#test');
console.log(test.parentElement);
document.body.innerHTML += '<span id="test2">0</span>';
console.log(test.parentElement);
```

```html
<span id="test">0</span>
```

If you don't want to re-select the element every time, you could set a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the container, and only re-select each element in the container when the HTML changes.

Comment: yes that or even create element and append it, unfortunately elements are added by third parties scripts and i dont control method of adding, so i have to work with what i have, so i will need to detect if it has been broken or something in that range

Comment: See edit. Check the element's `parentElement` or check to see if its container `contains` it.

Comment: this `.parentElement` check is brilliant! it does the job wonderfully, i havent tested yet the performance of both suggestions, but as initial look, it may seem that parentElement could be faster, as it only uses already stored reference to check its property. I could be wrong though, only tests could show the actual truth. Nevertheless this answer needs many upvotes, thank you ;)